# What is shaken optical lattice and why is it useful?

Tags: experimental-physics

I was reading some theoretical paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.00006 and they propose to use "shaken optical lattice" to experimentally realize the phase. I wonder what is shaken optical lattice and why it is useful in experiments.